# Partial query match in Access 2010 for two tables

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have two tables in Access 2010 - one is called Error Messages & one is called Sept.  I need to try and **partially** match a company_name field from Error Messages to a provider_name in Sept.  I have seen a few examples on the internet of how to do this but none are working.  This is my first time in Access in a very long time & I am not even sure where to build the query--I used Criteria Builder but it doesn't seem to work.  There are 14400 records so I can't manually do this.  Is this doable?  Any suggestions on how best to accomplish this task?

Comment: Please post your query or explain exactly what 'partially' is defined at. i.e. match the first 5 charcters, or characters 5-9, etc.

Comment: SELECT tbl_Error_Messages.PractName, tbl_Error_Messages.State, tbl_Error_Messages.PractName, tbl_Error_Messages.[OrgGrpName (from the Transformation Logs)], Sept.[State Code], Sept.Provider FROM tbl_Error_Messages INNER JOIN Sept ON tbl_Error_Messages.State = Sept.[State Code] WHERE (((tbl_Error_Messages.PractName) Like "*" & [Sept].[Provider] & "*"));

Comment: First, I see you have 'PractName' selected TWICE in your query - is that right?
Second, I see you are joining the tables on STATE, then *trying* to filter where PractName Like Provider -- however you are using the FULL string value.
Do you mean something like 'filter where the leftmost 5 positions match' or something similar?

Comment: Thx--I caught that when I posted this :)  I removed the extra one.  I need to match on Partial String if at all possible.  Here is the issue--one report has the name as JOHN DOE MD and one might have JOHN DOE, MD.  So the names aren't consistent so that is what I am trying to automatically try & partially match the string as much as possible.  There is no consistent way to pull like LEFT because our users typed what they wanted into one of the tables & our systems have something else.  Any ideas?   Also thank you so much for taking time to look at this with me :)

Comment: Users = Ugh! So really you don't need a 'like' or 'left' match because a user may also type 'DR JOHN DOE'? I have seen code around that will properly format names into prefix, FN, LN, suffix, but that would mean you need to run your names through that function, then try to compare. One option would be to create a Function and pass both strings to it to split and analyze. If it's an exact match, return a score of 5. If last name  & first name match, but other not, score = 4; etc. ????

Comment: That sounds like an option--the problem is that the list is so big & the variants are so all over the place since the Uggggh Users typed practice names however they wanted. I might be stuck doing it the slow and painstaking manual way at this rate though :(  Thx again for your suggestions